# ¿Como puedo sacar los comentarios de los articulos con dos tablas diferentes con php PDO MVC?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, pdo

este es mi primer mensaje en este foro.

Tengo que imprimir los resultados de varios apartados por ejemplo los artículos de la tabla "fes_articles" y los comentarios de la tabla "fes_comments".
Al principio me piden primero a la izquierda sacar el último artículo con su imagen y comentarios y lo hago de esta manera:

archivo-> controllers/gestorBlog.php

```
class BlogControllers{

 static public function ctrMostrarArticulosBlog(){

        $tabla1 = "fes_articles";               
        $tabla2 = "fes_files";
        $tabla3 = "fes_comments";       
        $idCategoria = 44;
        $idArticulo = 452; /*Prueba con artículo con dos comentarios*/          
        $idArticulo = 668;/*ÚLTIMO ARTÍCULO ACTUAL EN LA BASE DE DATOS, 0 comentarios*/     

        $respuesta = BlogModels::mdlMostrarArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla2, $tabla3, $idCategoria, $idArticulo);

        return $respuesta;

    } 
}
```

archivo -> models/gestorBlog.php

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class BlogModels{

static public function mdlMostrarArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla2, $tabla3, $idCategoria, $idArticulo){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT $tabla1.id, $tabla1.pages, $tabla1.categories, $tabla1.title, $tabla1.content, $tabla1.tags, $tabla2.name, $tabla2.ext, $tabla2.descriere, $tabla2.idx
            FROM $tabla1 
            INNER JOIN $tabla2 ON $tabla1.id = $tabla2.idx          
            WHERE $tabla1.categories = :idCategoria 
            AND $tabla1.id = :idArticulo
            ORDER by $tabla1.id DESC LIMIT 1 "); 

 $stmt -> bindParam(":idCategoria", $idCategoria, PDO::PARAM_STR);//Preguntar si se pone INT
        $stmt -> bindParam(":idArticulo", $idArticulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);//Preguntar si se pone INT
        $stmt -> bindParam(":comentarios", $comentarios, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch(); 

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;    
}

/*COMENTARIOS*/

public function mdlTotalComentariosArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla3, $idCategoria,$idArticulo){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT $tabla1.id, $tabla1.pages, $tabla1.categories, $tabla1.title, $tabla1.content, $tabla1.tags, $tabla3.id, $tabla3.categories, $tabla3.articles, COUNT($tabla3.content) as totalComentarios FROM $tabla1 
            INNER JOIN $tabla3 ON $tabla1.id = $tabla3.articles             
            WHERE $tabla1.id  = :idArticulo 
            ORDER by $tabla3.id");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":idArticulo", $idArticulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);                 

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll();

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;   

    }
}
```

y por último en el archivo de la vista:

archivo -> views/modules/blog.php

```
<?php
/* -- ARTÍCULO PRINCIPAL GRANDE -- */   

                $respuestaArticulos = BlogControllers::ctrMostrarArticulosBlog();

                $contenidoArticulos = substr($respuestaArticulos["content"], 0, 185);   

                echo'<section class="bloque-izq-cat">
                <article class="art-cat featured Article">
                <a class="thumb-art-cat" href="">

                <img  src="views/images/'.$respuestaArticulos['name'].'.'.$respuestaArticulos['ext'].'" title="'.$respuestaArticulos['descriere'].' " alt="'.$respuestaArticulos['descriere'].'"  />

                <span class="fecha-encima-art-cat dateOverlay">02 Jun 2017</span>
                <span class="num-encima-art-cat nrOverlay">0</span>
                </a>
                <h2 class="titulo-art-cat"><a href="">'.$respuestaArticulos["title"].'</a></h2>
                <p class="text-art-cat"><a href="">'.$contenidoArticulos.'</a></p>';                                

                /* ----- COMENTARIOS -------*/
                /*Aquí ver como puedo hacer para no repetir esta parte ya que vuelvo a traer los datos anteriores para consultar los comenatarios*/
                $tabla1 = "fes_articles";                                   
                $tabla3 = "fes_comments";               
                $idCategoriaComments = 44;
                $idArticuloComments = 452;/*Artículo de prueba con 2 comentarios*/                  
                $idArticulo = 668; /*ÚLTIMO ARTÍCULO ACTUAL EN LA BASE DE DATOS con 0 comentarios*/             

                $cantidadComentarios = BlogModels::mdlTotalComentariosArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla3, $idCategoriaComments, $idArticuloComments);

                foreach ($cantidadComentarios as $row => $item) {
                    $totalComentarios = $item["totalComentarios"];
                    if($totalComentarios > 1){
                        echo '<p class="fecha-y-comentario-mini-art-cat">junio 02, 2017 / <a href="">'.$totalComentarios.' comentarios</a></p>
                        </article>
                        </section>';
                    }

                    else if($totalComentarios == 1){
                        echo '<p class="fecha-y-comentario-mini-art-cat">junio 02, 2017 / <a href="">'.$totalComentarios.' comentario</a></p>

                        </article>
                        </section>';
                    }

                    else if($totalComentarios == 0){

                        echo '<p class="fecha-y-comentario-mini-art-cat">junio 02, 2017 / <a href="">0 comentarios</a></p>          
                        </article>
                        </section>';

                    }

                }
                /* ----- FIN COMENTARIOS -------*/

                /* -- FIN ARTÍCULO PRINCIPAL GRANDE -- */   
?>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien ya que si pongo el artículo de prueba 452 me sale perfectamente impreso y con el aviso de 2 comentarios y si pongo el último o incluso otros me sale con 0 o el número correspondiente.

Ahora tengo que hacer lo mismo con el resto de comentarios a imprimir, por ejemplo en la zona de la derecha vienen 5 artículos (del 2º más actual al 6ª) y hacer lo mismo para mostrar cuantos comentarios tiene cada uno. Sin embargo por mas vueltas que le doy no soy capaz.

Por ejemplo el archivo de los siguientes artículos lo uso así:

archivo-> controllers/gestorBlog.php

```
public function ctrMostrarMiniArticulosBlog(){      

        $tabla1 = "fes_articles";
        $tabla2 = "fes_files";
        $idCategoria = 44;      

        $respuesta = BlogModels::mdlMostrarMiniArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla2, $idCategoria);

        return $respuesta;

    }
```

archivo-> models/gestorBlog.php

```
public function mdlMostrarMiniArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla2, $idCategoria){


        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT $tabla1.id, $tabla1.pages, $tabla1.categories, $tabla1.title, $tabla1.content, $tabla1.tags, $tabla2.name, $tabla2.ext, $tabla2.descriere, $tabla2.idx
            FROM $tabla1 
            INNER JOIN $tabla2 ON $tabla1.id = $tabla2.idx          
            WHERE $tabla1.categories = :idCategoria             
            ORDER by $tabla1.id DESC LIMIT 1, 5");      

        $stmt -> bindParam(":idCategoria", $idCategoria, PDO::PARAM_STR);           

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll();

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;       

    }
```

archivo-> views/modules/blog.php

```
 $respuestaMiniArticulos = BlogControllers::ctrMostrarMiniArticulosBlog();

                echo '<section class="bloque-der-cat">';    

                foreach ($respuestaMiniArticulos as $row => $item) {
                    echo '<article class="mini-art-cat mini Article">
                    <a class="thumb-mini-art-cat" href="">      
                    <img  src="views/images/'.$item['name'].'.'.$item['ext'].'" title="'.$item['descriere'].' " alt="'.$item['descriere'].'"  /></a>
                    <h3 class="titulo-mini-art-cat"><a href="">'.$titulo.'</a></h3>
                    <p class="fecha-y-comentario-mini-art-cat">junio 01, 2017 / <a href="">';                   

                /* ----- COMENTARIOS MINI ARTÍCULOS -------*/

                /*AQUÍ LA DUDA*/

                /* ----- FIN COMENTARIOS MINI ARTÍCULOS -------*/   
}
```

La tabla comentarios solo existe para los artículos que tienen comentarios, es decir que si un artículo id=452 no tiene comentarios por lo tanto en la tabla comentarios no existe. 
¿Tengo entonces que hacer una consulta con dos comprobaciones? Primero una para ver si existe ese id comentario en comentarios y luego otra para ver si existe y relacionarlo con el id en la tabla artículos y hacer un recuento y por último todo eso a la vez aplicarlo en un foreach para ir haciendo el recuento

Como decía anteriormente aparte he intentado varias maneras que aquí no pongo, pero al final me estoy haciendo un lio ya que no logro darle a cada artículo con comentario su posición en el bloque foreach. ¿Como podría sacarlo o mejorarlo?

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Después de hacer varias pruebas, combinaciones, consultas etc etc creo que he logrado sacarlo haciendo pruebas en las consultas anteriores en mysql a través de phpmyadmin.

Ahora los archivos y códigos quedan así:

archivo-> controllers/gestorBlog.php

```
<?php

/*=============================================
CONTROLADOR DEL BLOG 
=============================================*/

class BlogControllers{

static public function ctrMostrarCategoriaBlog(){

        $tabla4 = "fes_categories";
        $idCategoria = 44;

        $respuesta = BlogModels::mdlMostrarCategoriaBlog($tabla4, $idCategoria);

        return $respuesta;

    }   

static public function ctrMostrarArticulosBlog(){       

        $tabla1 = "fes_articles";
        $tabla2 = "fes_files";
        $tabla3 = "fes_comments";       
        $idCategoria = 44;

        $respuesta = BlogModels::mdlMostrarArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla2, $tabla3, $idCategoria);

        return $respuesta;

    }

    static public function ctrMostrarMiniArticulosBlog(){       

        $tabla1 = "fes_articles";
        $tabla2 = "fes_files";
        $tabla3 = "fes_comments";       
        $idCategoria = 44;      

        $respuesta = BlogModels::mdlMostrarMiniArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla2, $tabla3, $idCategoria);

        return $respuesta;

    }
}
?>
```

archivo -> models/gestorBlog.php

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

/*=============================================
MODELO DEL BLOG
=============================================*/

class BlogModels{

    static public function mdlMostrarCategoriaBlog($tabla4, $idCategoria){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, title, content FROM $tabla4 WHERE id = :idCategoria");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":idCategoria", $idCategoria, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt->fetch();

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;       

    }

public function mdlMostrarArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla2, $tabla3, $idCategoria){       


        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT $tabla1.id, $tabla1.title, $tabla1.categories, $tabla1.content, $tabla1.tags, $tabla2.name, $tabla2.ext, $tabla2.descriere, $tabla2.idx,(SELECT COUNT($tabla3.content) as totalComentarios FROM $tabla3 WHERE $tabla3.articles = $tabla1.id and $tabla1.categories = :idCategoria) AS totalComentariosFinal
            FROM $tabla1
            INNER JOIN $tabla2 ON $tabla1.id = $tabla2.idx          
            WHERE $tabla1.categories = :idCategoria         
            ORDER by $tabla1.id DESC LIMIT 1");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":idCategoria", $idCategoria, PDO::PARAM_STR);               

        $stmt -> execute();     

        return $stmt->fetch();

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;       

    }  

    public function mdlMostrarMiniArticulosBlog($tabla1, $tabla2, $tabla3, $idCategoria){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT $tabla1.id, $tabla1.title, $tabla1.categories, $tabla1.content, $tabla1.tags, $tabla2.name, $tabla2.ext, $tabla2.descriere, $tabla2.idx,(SELECT COUNT($tabla3.content) as totalComentarios FROM $tabla3 WHERE $tabla3.articles = $tabla1.id and $tabla1.categories = :idCategoria) AS totalComentariosFinal
            FROM $tabla1
            INNER JOIN $tabla2 ON $tabla1.id = $tabla2.idx          
            WHERE $tabla1.categories = :idCategoria         
            ORDER by $tabla1.id DESC LIMIT 1, 5");      

        $stmt -> bindParam(":idCategoria", $idCategoria, PDO::PARAM_STR);                   

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll();

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;       

    }  

?>
```

archivo -> views/modules/blog.php

```
<?php                   

                /*=============================================
                VISTA DEL BLOG 
                =============================================*/ 

                /* -- CATEGORÍA -- */

                $respuestaCategoria = BlogControllers::ctrMostrarCategoriaBlog();

                echo '<header class="encabezado-cat cat-1">
                    <h1 class="nombre-cat"><a class=\'cursor-none\' href=\'javascript:void(0)\' rel="nofollow"><span>'.$respuestaCategoria["title"].'</span></a></h1>
                    </header>
                    <article class="textPage">'.$respuestaCategoria["content"].'</article>';        

                /* -- ARTÍCULO PRINCIPAL GRANDE -- */   

                $respuestaArticulos = BlogControllers::ctrMostrarArticulosBlog();

                $totalComentarios = $respuestaArticulos["totalComentariosFinal"];
                $contenidoArticulos = substr($respuestaArticulos["content"], 0, 185);   


                echo'<section class="bloque-izq-cat">
                    <article class="art-cat featured Article">
                    <a class="thumb-art-cat" href="">

                    <img  src="views/images/'.$respuestaArticulos['name'].'.'.$respuestaArticulos['ext'].'" title="'.$respuestaArticulos['descriere'].' " alt="'.$respuestaArticulos['descriere'].'"  />

                    <span class="fecha-encima-art-cat dateOverlay">02 Jun 2017</span>
                    <span class="num-encima-art-cat nrOverlay">0</span>
                    </a>
                    <h2 class="titulo-art-cat"><a href="">'.$respuestaArticulos["title"].'</a></h2>
                    <p class="text-art-cat"><a href="">'.$contenidoArticulos.'</a></p>';                

                /* ----- COMENTARIOS -------*/

                echo '<p class="fecha-y-comentario-mini-art-cat">junio 02, 2017 / <a href="">'.$totalComentarios.' comentarios Hola</a></p>         
                    </article>
                    </section>';    

                /* ----- FIN COMENTARIOS -------*/      

                /* -- FIN ARTÍCULO PRINCIPAL GRANDE -- */   


                /* -- MINI ARTÍCULOS--*/

                $respuestaMiniArticulos = BlogControllers::ctrMostrarMiniArticulosBlog();

                echo '<section class="bloque-der-cat">';    

                foreach ($respuestaMiniArticulos as $row => $item) {

                    $titulo = $item["title"];
                    $totalComentarios = $item["totalComentariosFinal"];

                    echo '<article class="mini-art-cat mini Article">
                    <a class="thumb-mini-art-cat" href="">      
                    <img  src="views/images/'.$item['name'].'.'.$item['ext'].'" title="'.$item['descriere'].' " alt="'.$item['descriere'].'"  /></a>
                    <h3 class="titulo-mini-art-cat"><a href="">'.$titulo.'</a></h3>
                    <p class="fecha-y-comentario-mini-art-cat">junio 01, 2017 / <a href="">';


                    /* ----- COMENTARIOS MINI ARTÍCULOS -------*/

                    echo '<p class="fecha-y-comentario-mini-art-cat">junio 02, 2017 / <a href="">'.$totalComentarios.' comentarios Hola</a></p>';

                    /* ----- FIN COMENTARIOS MINI ARTÍCULOS -------*/               

                    echo' </article>';

                }

                echo '</section>';  

                /* -- FIN MINI ARTÍCULOS--*/     
?>
```

Haciendo una nueva consulta con un select para contar los comentarios dentro de un mismo select para los artículos he logrado minimizar el proceso y parece que ahora va correctamente.

¿Se podría mejorar incluso esta manera de hacerlo?
Saludos.